# Neo4j relations

Tags: neo4j

I am new into graph databases, I've only used SQL based databases that's the reason i dont know how to implement m-n relationship in neo4j. In MySQL i would have 4 tables - Person, Job, Position, PersonHasJob.

Where table PersonHasJob has columns person_id, job_id, position_id, started [datetime].

Based on this I've created in neo4j these tables as separate nodes

where PersonHasJob has every property I've mentioned above (not IDs but Object way)

It looks kinda strange to me the way i see ouptut with this Middle node connecting everything.

Is there better way to define my nodes/relationships?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your graph model could look something like below. But it all depends...

1. Make your first model (whiteboard or use some tool like arrows https://arrows.app/)
2. Test the model (Does it support your domain questions)
3. If not, go back to 1.
4. Make a sample graph "instance model" (can be whiteboard/arrows or by loading some of the data into neo4j)
5. Test your domain questions (by doing walks in your graph / writing cypher queries)

Repeat until you have a model that supports all you queries well (both reads and writes).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your starting strategy of emulating a table in a node and joins as edges is okay. It's good that this looks strange to you!! Your entire world view will change as you move into the graph world. Traversing is much more efficient and scalable than joins.

Why are you setting up a graph database? The schema you develop will vary depending on the problem you are addressing. If you are looking for collaboration between companies or creating teams you would enhance your graph with additional nodes and edges. For job or company types you might use an ontology. Etc., etc. With these enhancements you have the option of using new properties or adding new nodes. For example, a job-type ontology could provide a code you put in the employee's node as a property. Alternatively you could have nodes of the job types and then an edge between the employee and his job type. The latter is much more robust.

Comment: I'm setting up graph database, because output of my program would be network graph, I'm trying to do some statistics in about half a bilion of nodes. In MySQL my program works just fine, but it takes about 5 seconds to complete my query. Then I noticed graph databases exists, so I wanted give it try.

Comment: 5 sec for 500,000,000 nodes is pretty good. Relational databases are good for many problems. You want to think graphs when traversals and collecting info along them are important. Neo4j is a database, so after you pull the relevant data you still have to run your statistics. Depending on what you are doing, it might run within the query using a PlugIn function(s) ... APOC, GDS (graph data science), etc.  But, you probably should stick with your existing, working solution.